# Displaying the user's computer name

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

I want to display the user's computer name in **Fourhundredone()** but the error keeps telling me I need an integer? *(TypeError: an integer is required (got type str))* is there any way to display it more correctly?

```
import socket
computer_name = socket.gethostname()
    def draw_text2(text, computer_name, text2, font, color, surface, x, y):
        font = pygame.font.Font("PixelDigivolve-mOm9.ttf",100)
        text = font.render(text + str(computer_name), text2, 1, color)
        text2= font.render(text2, 1, color)
        textRect = text.get_rect()
        textrect = textobj.get_rect()
        textrect.topleft = (x, y)
        surface.blit(textobj, textrect)

    def Fourhundredone():
        running = True
        while running:
             display_background(screen, clubroom)
             display_mai(screen,character_Mai)
             display_textbox()
             draw_text("Mai", font2, blood_red, screen, 2, 522)
             draw_text2("\"We can't be like you", computer_name, "!\"", font3, color, screen, 15, 580)

             for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == QUIT:
                    running = False
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
                if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                        running = False
                    if event.key == K_SPACE:
                        Fourhundredtwo()

             pygame.display.update()
             mainClock.tick(10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem isn't with the computer name, it would seem.

```
text = font.render(text + str(computer_name), text2, 1, color)
```

Looks wrong. You want to do (+ instead of ,):

```
text = font.render(text + str(computer_name) + text2, 1, color)
```

Outside the scope of the question, I'd recommend passing a single string that has been pre-formatted, instead of tailoring your function to the string you're trying to print.

Something like

```
def draw_text2(text, font, color, surface, x, y):
```

and called:

```
draw_text2(f"\"We can't be like you {computer_name}!\"", font3, color, screen, 15, 580)
```

or even

```
draw_text2("\"We can't be like you" + computer_name + "!\"", font3, color, screen, 15, 580)
```

if you don't want to bother with string formatting (although you should, it's much cleaner).

Any way you want to compose your string, passing it as a single parameter pre-formatted will make your function more re-usable.